# SQL worth updating from utf8_general_c to utf8_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

At some point in the past couple months I came across this article:

http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/

Which stated:

> The utf8_general_ci collation will do but ideally we want
>   utf8_unicode_ci. The former basically ignores all accents: it treats
>   ‘ü’ the same as ‘u’. The latter pays attention to accents; it’s a tiny
>   bit slower but more accurate.

To test the accuracy of that statement I updated an unpublished blog entry with the character `ü` while the database table structure for the relevant columns were set to `utf8_general_c` and the character was *not* converted to a regular `u`. I had previously seen the Swedish encoding and had, at the time, thought I had somehow inherited bad encodings from an old web hosting years ago.

So ultimately my question is whether or not I should update from `utf8_general_c` to `utf8_unicode_ci`? If not was there a fix in My SQL 5.5.27 or later that addressed the encoding issues mentioned on the referenced page?

Comment: Is `utf8_general_c` a typo?  If not, then please provide a reference to it.  I don't think such exists.

Answer (score 0):

The quote you gave is incorrect.  (And I emailed the author.)  In reality, both collations treat accented letters the same as unaccented letters.  That is the general case for all collations (in all MySQL versions) that are named "*_ci".

Also, capital 'U' is treated equal both of those characters (case-folding).  If you use `utf8_bin`, all three characters are treated unequal.

There are too-few collations that separate "case" from "accent", none for utf8.

"Collation" has to do with *comparisions*.  The characters are not "converted" as you suggest.

The reference to "Swedish" probably means that the `CHARACTER SET` used to be then-default `latin1`, which has a default `COLLATION latin1_swedish_ci`.

The main difference between `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` is that the latter looks at more than one character to decide on comparison.  (Note I said "character", not "byte".)

'ü' could also be written as two *characters*: a non-spacing double-dot plus a 'u'.  That encoding of 'ü' compares unequal to the one-character 'ü' in utf8_general_ci, but equal in utf8_unicode_ci.

To repeat, there is no 'fix' for what you describe, not even in the latest version, nor in MariaDB.

Are you only interested in European languages?  I don't think I have every seen someone use the 2-character version of 'ü' or any of the other European collation differences.  On the other hand, ligatures such as ij=ĳ and OE=oe=Œ=œ are visibly different. General treats them as different, but unicode treats them as equal.

Here is a list of the equivalence sets for utf8 collations:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html
The unicode collation is sort of generic for all languages, but 'wrong' for virtually every language.  That table points out many differences between, say, utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_turkish_ci.

Comment: It seems that your site, the blog entry and the tables passively suggest using `utf8_unicode_ci` if I want to ensure that characters that were typed intentionally have a fair greater chance of being correctly presented than other encodings such as `utf8_general_ci`. Can I get a solid yes please if that is the case? Not just European languages though I'm not interested in UTF16.

Comment: The 'best' available charset and collation for MySQL is `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  '520' refers to the Unicode standard; there is a newer version coming some day.  'mb4' gives you the 'rest' of Chinese, plus Emoji.  '520' improves the collations.

Comment: `utf8` and `utf8mb4` are _encodings_; `utf8_general_ci`, etc, are _collations_.  Please keep this distinction in mind.

Comment: I was explaining how there are two ways to _encode_ `ü`.  Both work (and have the same bytes) in both `utf8` and `utf8mb4`.  But _comparing_ `ü` gets more complicated because of the different collations, there being about 4 variations.  `utf16` is another `CHARACTER SET`; I don't consider it worth considering unless importing from some other application that uses that _encoding_.

Comment: As for a simple yes/no to "should I update"...  I have (I hope) provided you all the knowledge with which you can make that decision for yourself.  If you want the 'best' available today, do `ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  (That is _not_ `utf16`.)

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .